# Нужно передать значение переменной из файла php в файл js

Tags: javascript, php, html

HTML:

```
    <script src="../js/functions.js"></script>
    ..
    <body onload="lk()">
    ..
    <form method="post" style="margin-top:6vh;" action="../php/check_auth.php">
    <button class="reg" type="submit" name="enter" value="enter" onclick="lk()">Войти</button>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php 
$auth=0;
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','dfuGS_353sgas','glasssite');
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8mb4");
if(!$db){
    die('Ошибка невозможно подключиться: ');   
}
echo('Подключение успешно<br>');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password']; 

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT email FROM users WHERE '$email'=email AND '$password'=password");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
if($row==0){
    if(!$result){
        die('Ошибка ');   
    }
}
else{
    mysqli_close($db); 
    $auth=1;
    header('Location: ../html/auth.html');
    exit;  
}

mysqli_close($db);
```

?>

JS:

```
    function lk(){
if (auth=1){
    document.getElementById('ent').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('lk').style.display='block';
}
if(auth=0){
    document.getElementById('lk').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('ent').style.display='block';
}
```

}

Comment: что за значение? куда передать? что за функция ``lk()``?

Comment: https://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Comment: Передать нужно переменную auth. JS добавил

Comment: Что такое `auth` и откуда оно берется?

Comment: в PHP оно берётся. Мне нужно достать значение из php в js. Я не знаю как это сделать. Искал в интернете, но все то не работает, потому что у меня все не в одном файле

Comment: Так если в PHP берется, используйте data атрибут. [Использование data-* атрибутов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: `<script src="../js/functions.js"></script>` - поместите перед `</body>`

Comment: пробовал уже, не помогло

Comment: Как вариант, можно перед `header('Location: ../html/auth.html');` записать `$auth` в **cookie**, а в _auth.html_ с помощью JS получить `auth` из _cookie_.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего - в конец PHP файла добавить:

```
?>
<script> var auth=<?php echo $auth; ?>;</script>
```

Но лучше - разобраться с ajax запросами. Например, здесь: https://good-code.ru/ajax-zapros/

Comment: Не помогло. Пишет, что auth не найден